# Compile error in swift when accessing enum inside a Constant class

Tags: swift, enums

I have this code that won't compile.  The idea is I want to keep a global constant class.

ViewController.swift:

```
var user = [String: String]()    
user[CUser.Attribute.TYPE] = userTypeSwitch.on ? CUser.Type.RIDER.rawValue : CUser.Type.RIDER.rawValue
```

CUser.swift

```
class CUser {
  enum Type: String {
    case RIDER
    case DRIVER
  }
  class Attribute {
    static let TYPE = "TYPE"
  }
}
```

Error message is this: "Type 'CUser.Type' has no member 'RIDER'"

but when I enclose the enum type Type in with another dummy class it compiles fine.  Such that:

```
user[CUser.Attribute.TYPE] = userTypeSwitch.on ? CUser.Dummy.Type.RIDER.rawValue : CUser.Dummy.Type.RIDER.rawValue
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `Type` name inside a class because it's a **[Metatype Type](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html)**.

> A metatype type refers to the type of any type, including class types,
>   structure types, enumeration types, and protocol types.
>
> The metatype of a class, structure, or enumeration type is the name of
>   that type followed by **.Type**. The metatype of a protocol type—not the
>   concrete type that conforms to the protocol at runtime—is the name of
>   that protocol followed by .Protocol. For example, the metatype of the
>   class type SomeClass is SomeClass.Type and the metatype of the
>   protocol SomeProtocol is SomeProtocol.Protocol.

Just rename it.

Comment: So in other words, `Type` is a keyword?

Comment: Renamed it to TYPE.  Thank you  for the answer.